# A strange calculation error in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to calculate some data from 2 tables. When I do hand or (calculator) calculation, I get a different output than when I do it with a query. Can anyone please point what is the error?

When I do hand calculation, I get '10' as totalcard, but when I run this query, I get '41'. Does this have anything to do with indexes which don't have ANY relations with the column tbltrans.card.

Here is the code:

```
select
    ifnull((tbltrans2.qty*tbltrans2.price*(tbltrans.Discountper/100)),0) Total,
    ifnull(sum(tbltrans.card),0) totalcard
from tbltrans2,tbltrans
where tbltrans2.transid = tbltrans.transid 
    and tbltrans.saledate='06/01/2013'
```

here is my tbltrans:
[image]
and tbltrans2:
[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is syntactically valid. You're missing some parentheses on line 2.

Comment: What do you mean? Where exacty?

Comment: Line 2 of your code snippet. Count the number of opening parentheses. Then count the number of closing parentheses.

Comment: Even if i correct it, its still the same.

Comment: It was a typing mistake here

Comment: Have you tried to break apart the math operation to see which sub-result fails? (I still see a mismatch in the number of paren pairs btw)

Comment: Um no. But is there any logical mistakes in this staement?

Comment: If you run this exact query, you would get syntax error. Edit your question with the exact query you run and even better, with the data you have in the tables.

Comment: Please show the data you used, i.e. the result of `SELECT tbltrans.card FROM tbltrans2,tbltrans WHERE tbltrans2.transid = tbltrans.transid and tbltrans.saledate='06/01/2013'`

Comment: It's impossible to deduce what the values should be without the data. Could you make an example?

Comment: I believe if you run the query I showed above you'll see why the numbers don't match.

Comment: oh I got it.
so, How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple items per transaction, so the `card` field will show up once for each item record, so it will be summed multiple times for each transaction.

Your query also has another problem: you are using an aggregate function (`sum`) for the `card` column, but no aggregates for the other values.
What then happens is that SQLite computes *one* sum for the `card` values, which results in *one* result record.
To compute the `Total` value for this result record, SQLite doesn't know which of the `tbltrans`/`tbltrans2` records to use, so it just uses *one* random record from these tables.

To compute the correct `totalcard` value, you must not join the `tbltrans2` table in the same query:

```
SELECT ifnull(sum(tbltrans.card), 0) AS totalcard
FROM tbltrans
WHERE tbltrans.saledate = '06/01/2013'
```

The `Total` value might be computed with a subquery, but that depends on what its meaning should be. (Total discount per transaction? Total discount of all transactions on that date?)